# Why does System.Net.Mail.MailMessage implement IDisposable

Tags: .net, idisposable, mailmessage

So I've been using `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` objects for sending e-mail via `SmtpClient` for a while now. I noticed somewhere that `MailMessage` implements `IDisposable`, so I always use it within a `using` block.

```
using(MailMessage msg = new MailMessage())
{
    msg.To = blah... etc;
    ...
    smtpclient.Send(msg);
}
```

From metadata, you can see this info on the implementation of `MailMessage`

```
// Summary:
//     Releases all resources used by the System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.
[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
public void Dispose();
//
// Summary:
//     Releases the unmanaged resources used by the System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
//     and optionally releases the managed resources.
//
// Parameters:
//   disposing:
//     true to release both managed and unmanaged resources; false to release only
//     unmanaged resources.
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing);
```

But I'm wondering, why does `MailMessage` implement `IDisposable`? It does not appear to have anything to do with network-related items, because the `SmtpClient` handles all that.

Could it be due to potentially holding file handles for attached files? Is there something else there I'm forgetting?

Comment: The attachments need to be closed, for one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to dotPeek, it is disposing of its attachments and its views:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
  if (!disposing || this.disposed)
    return;
  this.disposed = true;
  if (this.views != null)
    this.views.Dispose();
  if (this.attachments != null)
    this.attachments.Dispose();
  if (this.bodyView == null)
    return;
  this.bodyView.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It implements IDisposable because it has children that implement IDisposable.  For instance, Attachment is a disposable object because an attachment can be a Stream, which most of the time needs disposing.  So, after the message has been sent off, disposal of the message is required for disposal of the attachment (which holds a stream).

Answer (score 5):

The `MailMessage` type has several fields which it owns and that implement `IDisposable`.  Proper implementation of the `IDisposable` pattern requires that it also implements `IDisposable` and chains the call to those fields.  In particular attachments, views, and body view

Answer (score 4):

If you supply images or attachments, then those need to be cleaned up on disposal.  As such, calling dispose either implicitly in a using or explicitly is something you should do.

In general, always call dispose on any object that implements IDisposable.  They wouldn't have implemented it if it wasn't necessary.

Comment: I almost stopped myself from clicking to upvote when I read "they wouldn't have implemented it if it wasn't necessary", because as an example, everything I've read says that it's not necessary on the Linq to SQL `DataContext` object. There are also ASP.NET MVC Helpers which use it as a bit of syntactical tooling, but it's not at all necessary; such as the object returned by `Html.BeginForm`; all it does when Disposed is output the end of the form. +1 anyway for generally good advice.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - By that definition, it's never "necessary" to call dispose, since the GC will eventually call it.  However, what I should have said was "highly desireable", given that one never knows when Dispose will eventually be called.

Comment: What you've said about the importance of calling `Dispose` or using `using` is very important and excellent advice, so I don't want to appear to be generally in opposition to it. However, it is actually *not* desirable to call it in some cases with the MVC helpers I note, such as when you are outputting the closing `</form>` tag manually, somewhere. Granted; I've never used that (or similar) helpers and not used the `using` syntax associated with them.

Comment: @Mystere Man: The GC will *never* call `Dispose`. (*If* the object in question has a fallback finaliser then the GC should eventually call that.)

Comment: @LukeH - You're being pedantic.  While true, it happens during the GC.  The rule is that the finalizer calls Dispose if it hasn't already been called.  While it's possible someone created a disposable object without a finalizer, or that they didn't follow the IDisposable pattern, i would consider such software to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the original source code to see exactly what it currently does. See [MailMessage.Dispose](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/net/System/Net/mail/MailMessage.cs.html#149b686c70a3e745). I haven't included the source code here because I don't know if it's allowed.

Comment: This isn't really an answer though. You don't need to post the code; just describe why it's needed... so just sort of summarize what it's doing.

Comment: @AndrewBarber, my point was the original source code is more authoritative and up-to-date than the decompiled code in the accepted answer. So if anyone wants to see for themselves, the link in this answer is a quick way to do so.

Comment: Probably, yes. And that'd be superb as a comment on the accepted answer or the question. Or there are probably a couple tidbits of additional info you could add from that. That said; this *is* useful info related to this topic, which is why I encouraged adding some info :)